# Switch for making background map from Mapbox visible/invisible in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, mapbox

I'm building a Voronoi map inspired by http://chriszetter.com/blog/2014/06/15/building-a-voronoi-map-with-d3-and-leaflet/. I'd like to make an option to turn off the background map as the location of the data may not be relevant in all my use cases. Furthermore, it would be great if the visualization could work offline this way. After toggling the switch, the entire background would be white. The Voronoi overlap would be the same. How do I do that? Here's the code (zip-file contains the csv-files): https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8vtfh8mkxazfr0/voronoi-maps-master.zip?dl=0

**EDIT:** There's two layer variables in the original code as I was trying to split the visualization into two. However, that attempt was unsuccessful and only `mapLayer` is used. This may not have been clear in the original question.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.3/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div id='map'>
  </div>
  <div id='loading'>
  </div>
  <!-- <div id='selected'>
    <h1>...</h1>
  </div> -->
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.8/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.3/mapbox.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="/voronoi-map/lib/voronoi_map.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="voronoi_map.js"></script>
  <script>
    map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'zetter.i73ka9hn') // <- dur ikke!
      .fitBounds([[59.355596 , -9.052734], [49.894634 , 3.515625]]);

    url = 'supermarkets.csv';
    initialSelection = d3.set(['Tesco', 'Sainsburys']);
    voronoiMap(map, url, initialSelection);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**voronoi_map.js**

```
voronoiMap = function(map, url, initialSelections) {
  var pointTypes = d3.map(),
      points = [],
      lastSelectedPoint;

  var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
      .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
      .y(function(d) { return d.y; });

  var selectPoint = function() {
    d3.selectAll('.selected').classed('selected', false);

    var cell = d3.select(this),
        point = cell.datum();

    lastSelectedPoint = point;
    cell.classed('selected', true);

    d3.select('#selected h1')
      .html('')
      .append('a')
        .text( /*point.name*/ "8 interactions from this cell")
        /* .attr('href', point.url)
        .attr('target', '_blank') */
  }

  var drawWithLoading = function(e){
    d3.select('#loading').classed('visible', true);
    if (e && e.type == 'viewreset') {
      d3.select('#overlay').remove();
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
      draw();
      d3.select('#loading').classed('visible', false);
    }, 0);
  }

  var draw = function() {
    d3.select('#overlay').remove();

    var bounds = map.getBounds(),
        topLeft = map.latLngToLayerPoint(bounds.getNorthWest()),
        bottomRight = map.latLngToLayerPoint(bounds.getSouthEast()),
        existing = d3.set(),
        drawLimit = bounds.pad(0.4);

    filteredPoints = points.filter(function(d) {
      var latlng = new L.LatLng(d.latitude, d.longitude);

      if (!drawLimit.contains(latlng)) { return false };

      var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(latlng);

      key = point.toString();
      if (existing.has(key)) { return false };
      existing.add(key);

      d.x = point.x;
      d.y = point.y;
      return true;
    });

    voronoi(filteredPoints).forEach(function(d) { d.point.cell = d; });

    var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg")
      .attr('id', 'overlay')
      .attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide")
      .style("width", map.getSize().x + 'px')
      .style("height", map.getSize().y + 'px')
      .style("margin-left", topLeft.x + "px")
      .style("margin-top", topLeft.y + "px");

    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (-topLeft.x) + "," + (-topLeft.y) + ")");

    var svgPoints = g.attr("class", "points")
      .selectAll("g")
        .data(filteredPoints)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "point");

    var buildPathFromPoint = function(point) {
      return "M" + point.cell.join("L") + "Z";
    }


    svgPoints.append("path")
      .attr("class", "point-cell")
      .attr("d", buildPathFromPoint)
      //.style('fill', function(d) { return '#' + d.color } )
      .on('click', selectPoint)
      .classed("selected", function(d) { return lastSelectedPoint == d} );

    /* svgPoints.append("circle")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      .style('fill', function(d) { return '#' + d.color } )
      .attr("r", 2); */
  }

/* function interactionGradient() {
    color = 

    if 
    return 
} */


  var mapLayer = {
    onAdd: function(map) {
      map.on('viewreset moveend', drawWithLoading);
      drawWithLoading();
    }
  };

  var voronoiLayer = {
    onAdd: function(map) {
      map.on('viewreset moveend', drawWithLoading);
      drawWithLoading();
    }
  };


  map.on('ready', function() {
    d3.csv(url, function(csv) {
      points = csv;
      points.forEach(function(point) {
        pointTypes.set(point.type, {type: point.type, color: point.color});
      })
      map.addLayer(mapLayer);
    })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the tileLayer seperately so you can create a reference to it which you can then in turn use to create a layercontrol which can easily enable/disable layers:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGF1bC12ZXJob2V2ZW4iLCJhIjoiZ1BtMWhPSSJ9.wQGnLyl1DiuIQuS0U_PtiQ';

// Create the tileLayer.
var tileLayer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('examples.map-i86nkdio');

var map = L.mapbox.map('mapbox', null, { // Do not add as parameter
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 1,
    // Add here so it still gets added to the map initially
    // You could skip this so it won't be added and you can
    // turn it on via the layercontrol
    'layers': [tileLayer] 
});

// Create layer control
var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, {
    'Tilelayer': tileLayer // Add tile layer to overlays
}).addTo(map);
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5re3o6qnyCwAqXNYXrkP?p=preview

L.mapbox.tileLayer reference: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.5/l-mapbox-tilelayer/

L.control.layers reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers

Edit because of the comments:

You're already working with separate layers, the tilelayer (background) gets added upon map initalization `L.mapbox.map('map', 'zetter.i73ka9hn')` that in fact calls: `L.mapbox.tileLayer('zetter.i73ka9hn').addTo(map)`. You'll need to do it that way because you'll need a reference to the layer so you can add it to `L.control.layers` like shown above. Your voronoi layer gets added in the `voronoiMap` method in the `ready` handler of the map: `map.addLayer(mapLayer);`

Thus as you can see they are already separated. Now if you also want to be able to toggle the voronoi layer in your layer control you'll need to add it to the layer control:

```
map.on('ready', function() {
    d3.csv(url, function(csv) {
        points = csv;
        points.forEach(function(point) {
            pointTypes.set(point.type, {
                type: point.type,
                color: point.color
            });
        });
        map.addLayer(mapLayer);
        layerControl.addOverlay(mapLayer, 'Voronoi'); // Here
    })
});
```

But that in itself is not enough in your case because your layer doesn't have a `onRemove` method as prescribed by the ILayer interface:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#ilayer

Now if we add a `onRemove` method to your layer like this:

```
var mapLayer = {
    onAdd: function(map) {
        map.on('viewreset moveend', drawWithLoading);
        drawWithLoading();
    },
    onRemove: function (map) {
        d3.select('#overlay').remove();
    }
};
```

It works: http://plnkr.co/edit/3z3pCAo0gGuA7xqnqiqb?p=preview (note i've commented out the `ready` handler because the map is ready before the function call so it wouldn't fire and changed some colors to make things more clear.) Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks good! I've been trying to separate the current code (especially in the 'draw'-function) into two separate layers so I can draw the voronoi without the background map, but without any luck as they seem to be too intertwined. How would you separate the two layers in the voronoi_map.js?

Comment: How is it out of the current context? From my question: "After toggling the switch, the entire background would be white. The Voronoi overlap would be the same." With the layer control I can turn off the layer, but that disables **both** the background and the Voronoi overlay as they are implemented as one layer in the code. This simply turns off the visualization entirely. In order for it to work the visualization need to be split into two layers. To summarize: My comment is describing how I've been trying to expand your answer to solve the problem :)

Comment: I'm completely not following what you're asking. In your code you're adding the tilelayer separately in the index.html, the voronio gets added seperately in the voronoiMap method. They are seperated? I must be really overlooking something here or completely misunderstanding what you want.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added an example so you can clearly see that you're already working with two separate layers.